# With MySQL, how to count members who are in an option and not in an other one?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I would like to display some datas of a member table.

My table looks like this (extract of the table structure):

```
id_member | city_member | option1  | no option 2
-----------------------------------------------
   1      |   Paris     |    1     |    0
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   2      |   Berlin    |    1     |    0
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   3      |   Berlin    |    0     |    1
```

Here an example of the expected result (after a sql query):

```
city_member | members | option1  | non_option2
-----------------------------------------------
   Paris    |   200   |    150   |   47
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   London   |   325   |    286   |   189
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   Berlin   |   124   |    110   |   12
```

Explanation: There is 200 members living in Paris. Among them, 150 have chosen the option 1. Among members who have chosen option 1 and who live in Paris, 47 of them don't have chosen option 2.

I tried this query but it only works for the first three columns. I need help to find how to do for the fourth one.

```
SELECT city_member, 
    COUNT(id_member) AS members, 
    SUM(option1) AS option1, 
    SUM(option1 - option2) AS non_option2
FROM my_table
GROUP by city_member
```

How to do something like "COUNT member WHERE option2 = '0' AND WHO ARE IN option1 AS non_option2"?

Comment: 1 - do you want a sql statement ?

Comment: as i inderstand do you want number of members that have not option1 and option2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without having a mysql atm: I'm just guessing:

```
SELECT city_member, 
COUNT(id_member) AS members, 
SUM(option1) AS option1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN option1 = '1' AND option2 = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS non_option2
FROM my_table
GROUP by city_member
```

edit: fixed SQL

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    city_member, 
    COUNT(*) AS members, 
    SUM(option1) AS option1, 
    SUM(option1 * option2) AS option1_and_2,
    SUM(option1 * (1-option2)) AS option1_and_non_option2
FROM my_table
GROUP by city_member
```